# How to create a column in SharePoint list that reflects a previous value?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, infopath

I am using an InfoPath form that has a field which changes value. How do I create a column that only reflects the very first value despite all the changes done. I am on SharePoint Online by the way.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating an extra column (Eg: Column_Original) in the list which only stores the value when new list item is created?

On list item creation, run an **automated Power Automate flow** (with **new item created** as the trigger) which *copies the value from Column X to Column_Original* (Column which will store the original value).

On subsequent updates to this item, updates will only be made to Column X and not Column_Original.